# Converting Linear json to nested json in mule

Tags: java, json, mule

I need help in the logic for transforming one json file to another json file. I am trying to achieve this in mule without dataweave in the custom java component.

I want to convert a linear json to nested json, The input data is a linear json containing the details of all files and directory in particular FTP server. The output Json file should be able to nest the files and directory based on the root directory. Here is the example of input and output json.

```
{
  "InputJson": [
    {
      "type": "dir",
      "id": "RootDir",
      "name": "abcd",
      "Dir": "/abcd"
    },
    {          
      "type": "dir",
      "name": "Folder1",
      "Dir": "/abcd/Folder1",
      "id": "XXXXX"
    },
    {          
      "type": "file",
      "name": "Folder1SubFolder1",
      "Dir": "/abcd/Folder1/Folder1SubFolder1",
      "id": "XXXXXX"
    },
    {          
      "type": "dir",
      "name": "Folder2",
      "Dir": "/abcd/Folder2"
      "id": "XXXXXX"
    },
    {          
      "type": "dir",
      "name": "Folder2SubFolder1",
      "Dir": "/abcd/Folder2/Folder2SubFolder1"
      "id": "XXXXXX"
    },
    {          
      "type": "file",          
      "name": "Folder2SubFolder1SubFolder1",
      "Dir": "/abcd/Folder2/Folder2SubFolder1/Folder2SubFolder1SubFolder1"
      "id": "XXXXXX"
    }   
    ]
}
```

### Output

```
    {
    "id": "RootDir",
    "value": "Files",
    "type": "folder"
    "OutData": [{
        "value": "Folder1",
        "OutData": [{
        "value": "Folder1SubFolder1"
        }       
       ]
     }
    ]
    "OutData": [{
        "value": "Folder2",
        "OutData": [{
        "value": "Folder2SubFolder1",
        "OutData":[{
         "value": "Folder2SubFolder1SubFolder1",
        }]
       }        
     ]
    }
   ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### the logic

```
1. CREATE   (java) `outputElemtsList` = []  
2. FOR EACH (json) `inputElement` IN `InputJson`
3.   CREATE (java) `outputElemt`
4.   ADD   `outputElement` TO `outputElemtsList`
5.   IF    `outputElement` HAS `parent`
6.     ADD `outputElement` TO  `parent`.outData
7. CONVERT `outputElemtsList`[0] TO `Json`
```

assuming, the list in `InputJson`, is ordered in the same as the sample, (the child never come before their parent)

if not, you'll need to add some checks as:

```
3. create `outputElement` if not in `outputElemtsList`; else continue
6. create `parent` if not in `outputElemtsList`
```

---

### in practice

you can use a Json parser, such [jakson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), to:

```
// parse InputJson, to Java Objects 
Map<String, Object> rootNode = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);

// ... implement the logic  ...

// serialize a java Object into Json 
String outputJson = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(routOutputs);
```

### the code

**updated** to distinguish between file and folders(dir)

1- `OutputElement` class

```
public class OutputElement {
    String id, value, type;

    public void addOutData(OutputElement outputElement) {}

    // constructor, accessors ...
}
```

1.2- `class OutputDir extends OutputElement`

```
public class OutputElement {
    List<OutputElement> outData = new ArrayList<>();                 

    @Override
    public void addOutData(OutputElement outputElement) {        
        this.outData.add(outputElement);
    }
}
```

2- `Main` class : `LinearToNestedJson`

method to check if outputElements List contains an outputElement

```
public static boolean contains(List<OutputElement> outputElements, String value) {
    for (OutputElement outputElement : outputElements) {
        if (outputElement.getValue().equals(value))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`main` method

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JacksonTester tester = new JacksonTester();
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = IN_JSON;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> rootNode = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Map<String, Object>> inputElemnts = 
            (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) rootNode.getOrDefault("InputJson", null);
        List<OutputElement> outputElements = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map inputElemnt : inputElemnts) {
            String fullpath = (String) inputElemnt.get("Dir");
            String[] tree = fullpath.substring(1).split("/");
            final int deepth = tree.length;
            String dirName = tree[deepth - 1];

            final String value = (String) inputElemnt.get("name");
            final String id = (String) inputElemnt.get("id");
            String type = (String) inputElemnt.get("type");                
            OutputElement outputElement;

            if (type != null && type.equals("dir")) {
                outputElement = new OutputDir();
            } else {
                if(type==null) type = "file";
                outputElement = new OutputElement();
            }

            outputElement.setValue(value);
            outputElement.setId(id);
            outputElement.setType(type);

            if (!contains(outputElements, value)) {
                outputElements.add(outputElement);
            }

            if (deepth > 1) {
                String parentName = tree[deepth - 2];

                for (OutputElement element : outputElements) {
                    if (element.getValue().equals(parentName)) {
                        element.addOutData(outputElement);
                    }
                }
            }

//            for (int i = 0; i < deepth -1; i++) {
//                System.out.println(tree[i]);
//            }
        }
        OutputElement routOutputs = outputElements.get(0);
        String outputJson = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                                  .writeValueAsString(routOutputs);

        System.out.println(outputJson);

    } catch (JsonParseException | JsonMappingException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

it's **output**, for the given input (after [validation](http://jsonlint.com/))

```
{
  "id" : "RootDir",
  "value" : "abcd",
  "type" : "dir",
  "outData" : [ {
    "id" : "XXXXX",
    "value" : "Folder1",
    "type" : "dir",
    "outData" : [ {
      "id" : "XXXXXX",
      "value" : "Folder1SubFolder1",
      "type" : "file"
    } ]
  }, {
    "id" : "XXXXXX",
    "value" : "Folder2",
    "type" : "dir",
    "outData" : [ {
      "id" : "XXXXXX",
      "value" : "Folder2SubFolder1",
      "type" : "dir",
      "outData" : [ {
        "id" : "XXXXXX",
        "value" : "Folder2SubFolder1SubFolder1",
        "type" : "file"
      } ]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Comment: I know this, but I need help for the logic how to create nested json from linear one. Basically I am stuck at data transformation

Comment: Thats perfect. It works like a magic. I have a slight change in the requirement. It is the change in the output json. If the type is a 'file' not 'folder', I do not want outData[] to be populated, I have attached the example output json. Can you please modify your answer and let me know how it should work for a file

Comment: your `inpueJson` doesn't contain a field `type`. you could either add this field to the `inputeJson` elements, or add a test a logic test in the java implementation.. : if `inputeElement.Dir` end with '/' -> it's a folder else it's a file (hint: use [java regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)) for that

Comment: It does have a type which tells me if it is folder or file. But with your logic when it's file an empty outData is populating

Comment: I've created this [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134330/json2mule) to continue this discussion

Comment: when it's file an empty outData is created, and it still emtpy. you can set it to null befor adding the input element to its parent. or ...
anyway, i think the **I want to convert a linear json to nested json,** is a already answered, so all you still need to do is adapt the answer to your Personal case/data

Answer (score 1):

Use [groupBy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#group-by) - that's exactly what you need. 
Here is code:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
items : payload.InputJson groupBy $.id pluck {
    id: $$,
    values: $
}
```

Here is result:
[image]

Comment: I am using Community edition, so I cant use data weave

Comment: Then you have to do it Java which is much easier. At least for me.